# Python3 - How to write a number to a file using a variable and sum it with the current number in the file

Tags: python-3.x, addition

Suppose I have a file named test.txt and it currently has the number 6 inside of it. I want to use a variable such as x=4 then write to the file and add the two numbers together and save the result in the file.

```
    var1 = 4.0
    f=open(test.txt)
    balancedata = f.read()
    newbalance = float(balancedata) + float(var1)
    f.write(newbalance)
    print(newbalance)
    f.close()
```

Comment: You can first get the content of the file, 6, save that as a variable, convert it to an int. Then add that and the variable and print it, make sure you are adding two ints. Then, you can use `open` and write mode. Write the variable that you stored 6 in, add x and set it equal to the result of when you added it.

Comment: Hey, I added some code. Currently I am getting an error "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not float". But my issue is I want to use a float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably simpler than you're trying to make it:

```
variable = 4.0

with open('test.txt') as input_handle:
    balance = float(input_handle.read()) + variable

with open('test.txt', 'w') as output_handle:
    print(balance, file=output_handle)
```

Make sure 'test.txt' exists before you run this code and has a number in it, e.g. 0.0 -- you can also modify the code to deal with creating the file in the first place if it's not already there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Files only read and write strings (or `bytes` for files opened in binary mode). You need to convert your float to a string before you can write it to your file.

Probably `str(newbalance)` is what you want, though you could customize how it appears using `format` if you want. For instance, you could round the number to two decimal places using `format(newbalance, '.2f')`.

Also note that you can't write to a file opened only for reading, so you probably need to either use mode `'r+'` (which allows both reading and writing) combined with a `f.seek(0)` call (and maybe `f.truncate()` if the length of the new numeric string might be shorter than the old length), or close the file and reopen it in `'w'` mode (which will truncate the file for you).

Comment: Thank you, I will try to keep that in mind for the future. I did not know that.